# How to generate oracle specific queries django

Tags: django, oracle

How can I get Django to produce/submit the exact query below:

```
SELECT "MESSAGE"."MSG_NO", "MESSAGE"."MSG_TYPE", "MESSAGE"."DIRECTION", "MESSAGE"."SESSION_NO", "MESSAGE"."SEQUENCE_NO", "MESSAGE"."REF_SESSION", "MESSAGE"."REF_SEQUENCE", "MESSAGE"."ACKTIME", "MESSAGE"."ACKNAKSTATUS", "MESSAGE"."PRIORITY", "MESSAGE"."DELIVMONITOR", "MESSAGE"."OBSOLESCENCE", "MESSAGE"."DISPOSITION", "MESSAGE"."TRAILER", "MESSAGE"."BYPASSED", "MESSAGE"."RESPONSE_QUEUE", "MESSAGE"."SOURCE_QUEUE", "MESSAGE"."QUEUE", "MESSAGE"."QUEUE_PRIORITY", "MESSAGE"."DATE_CREATED", "MESSAGE"."DATE_ROUTED", "MESSAGE"."INPUT_FILE", "MESSAGE"."OUTPUT_FILE", "MESSAGE"."STATUS1", "MESSAGE"."STATUS2", "MESSAGE"."STATUS3", "MESSAGE"."USERID", "MESSAGE"."TMSTAMP" 
FROM "MESSAGE" 
WHERE ("MESSAGE"."DATE_CREATED" >= (SYSDATE-3) 
AND "MESSAGE"."DIRECTION" = 0 
AND "MESSAGE"."STATUS1" = 0)
```

The below code produces a query that does not work:

```
Message.objects.using(queue_db_env).filter(STATUS1=0, DIRECTION=0, DATE_CREATED__gte=time_threshold)
```

Below is the query produced by the code above and it does not work when I run it manually:

```
SELECT "MESSAGE"."MSG_NO", "MESSAGE"."MSG_TYPE", "MESSAGE"."DIRECTION", "MESSAGE"."SESSION_NO", "MESSAGE"."SEQUENCE_NO", "MESSAGE"."REF_SESSION", "MESSAGE"."REF_SEQUENCE", "MESSAGE"."ACKTIME", "MESSAGE"."ACKNAKSTATUS", "MESSAGE"."PRIORITY", "MESSAGE"."DELIVMONITOR", "MESSAGE"."OBSOLESCENCE", "MESSAGE"."DISPOSITION", "MESSAGE"."TRAILER", "MESSAGE"."BYPASSED", "MESSAGE"."RESPONSE_QUEUE", "MESSAGE"."SOURCE_QUEUE", "MESSAGE"."QUEUE", "MESSAGE"."QUEUE_PRIORITY", "MESSAGE"."DATE_CREATED", "MESSAGE"."DATE_ROUTED", "MESSAGE"."INPUT_FILE", "MESSAGE"."OUTPUT_FILE", "MESSAGE"."STATUS1", "MESSAGE"."STATUS2", "MESSAGE"."STATUS3", "MESSAGE"."USERID", "MESSAGE"."TMSTAMP" 
FROM "MESSAGE" 
WHERE ("MESSAGE"."DATE_CREATED" >= 2018-09-15 12:47:43.784709 
AND "MESSAGE"."DIRECTION" = 0 
AND "MESSAGE"."STATUS1" = 0)
```

This is due to `"MESSAGE"."DATE_CREATED" >= 2018-09-15 12:47:43.784709` , query only works when I swap out the `DATE_CREATE` clause with `"MESSAGE"."DATE_CREATED" >= (SYSDATE-3)`

My views.py has the code of:

```
class MessageList(APIView):
  def get(self, request, queue_db_env, queue_name, queue_id, format=None):
      #
      # time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=36)
      now = timezone.now()
      time_threshold = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=36)
      print(time_threshold.timestamp())

      str_time_threshold = time_threshold.timestamp()

      #
      messages = Message.objects.using(queue_db_env).filter(STATUS1=0, DIRECTION=0, DATE_CREATED__gte=time_threshold)
      print(messages.query)
      serializer = MessageSerializer(messages, many=True)

      return Response({"Queue": queue_name, "Queue_ID": queue_id, "Queue_Messages": serializer.data})
```

My models.py is:

```
from django.db import models

class Message(models.Model):
  MSG_NO = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,)
  MSG_TYPE = models.IntegerField()
  DIRECTION = models.IntegerField()
  SESSION_NO = models.IntegerField()
  SEQUENCE_NO = models.IntegerField()
  REF_SESSION = models.IntegerField()
  REF_SEQUENCE = models.IntegerField()
  ACKTIME = models.DateTimeField(max_length = 7)
  ACKNAKSTATUS = models.IntegerField()
  PRIORITY = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
  DELIVMONITOR = models.IntegerField()
  OBSOLESCENCE = models.IntegerField()
  DISPOSITION = models.IntegerField()
  TRAILER = models.IntegerField()
  BYPASSED = models.IntegerField()
  RESPONSE_QUEUE = models.IntegerField()
  SOURCE_QUEUE = models.IntegerField()
  QUEUE = models.IntegerField()
  QUEUE_PRIORITY = models.IntegerField()
  DATE_CREATED = models.DateTimeField()
  DATE_ROUTED = models.DateTimeField()
  INPUT_FILE = models.IntegerField()
  OUTPUT_FILE = models.IntegerField()
  STATUS1 = models.IntegerField()
  STATUS2 = models.IntegerField()
  STATUS3 = models.IntegerField()
  USERID = models.CharField(max_length = 8)
  TMSTAMP = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to filter on last 3 days on `DATE_CREATED` colument

I am using an oracle database and I am failing to filter on date.

Comment: When you say *"does not work"* do you mean it fails with an error message? Or just produces an incorrect results???

Answer (score 2):

> `time_threshold = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=36)`

There are twenty-four hours in a day. So 36 hours = 1.5 days. If you want to filter on the last three days you need

```
timedelta(hours=72)
```